# Can't bind params in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to bind params in node js and this is my code but shows some erros,

```
app.get("/single/:id", async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    try{
        const singleMovie = await Movies.findById(id)
        res.render("single", {
        singleMovie: singleMovie
    });
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});
```

shows me this warning,

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model 
>   "Movies" and id is undifined

any way to fix this?

Comment: What is the console.log out put and model definition

Comment: just for check the req.params.id has value or undifined

Comment: if the id is != undefined maybe you should build an [ObjectID object](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html)

Comment: You should replace res.render() with res.json() in your code.

Comment: can you show the url whcih you are hitting, i just want to see the value of id

Answer (score 3):

In your code `res.render("single", {` should be `res.json("single", {`

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below... sending the response in json just to test it....
if you get the same error you are getting, then there is a problem somewhere in your code. Because The block of code you posted looks fine!

```
app.get("/single/:id", async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    try{
        const singleMovie = await Movies.findById(id)
        res.json({
        singleMovie: singleMovie
    });
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});
```

Also make sure you are using `nodejs -v 8+` and `mongoose -v 5+`

Comment: Actually i want pass singleMovie to the template and display them not just see the result